# Calling method down through an extension chain in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public abstract class Superclass
{
    public Superclass()
    {
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        //clear variables in Superclass class
        System.out.println("superclass cleared.");
        clear1();
    }

    public abstract void clear1();
}

public class Subclass1 extends Superclass
{
    public Subclass1(){}

    @Override
    public void clear1()
    {
        //clear variables in Subclass1 class
        System.out.println("subclass1 cleared.");
        clear2();
    }

    public abstract void clear2() {}


public class Subclass2 extends Subclass1
{
    public Subclass2() {};

    @Override
    public void clear2()
    {
        //clear variables in Subclass2 class
        System.out.println("subclass2 cleared.");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Subclass2 c2 = new Subclass2();
    c2.clear();
}
```

Hello all! I created this extension chain that has a method for clearing variables in each class. When clear() is called, clear1() and clear2() methods are called clearing variables in Superclass, Subclass1 and Subclass2. However, creating new methods like clear3(), clear4()... as this extension chain gets deeper seems inefficient and repetitive. Is there a better way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just have the `clear()` method and have the override in each subclass call the super implementation.

```java
public class Parent {
  public void clear() { 
    System.out.println("Parent cleared"); 
  }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  @Override public void clear() {
    super.clear();
    System.out.println("Child cleared");
  }
}

public class Grandchild extends Child {
  @Override public void clear() {
    super.clear();
    System.out.println("Grandchild cleared");
  }
}
```

Then if you do:

```java
Parent obj = new Grandchild();
obj.clear();
```

You'll see the following output:

```
Parent cleared
Child cleared
Grandchild cleared
```

If you want the cleanup to happen bottom-up instead to top-down then simply make the `super.clear()` call last instead of first.

Comment: That's a great solution thank you. but is there a way to achieve it without consciously remembering to add "super.clear()" in every clear()? something like forcing the programmer to add the line.

Comment: Not in plain Java. I believe there are third-party libraries that can help with this, though I've never used any of them. Note the ["call super"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super) approach in my answer appears to be regarded as an anti-pattern, but I personally can't think of an alternative given your requirements/constraints.